# SqlServer convert to mySql5.5 ,jpa @GeneratedValue does not work

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

When I convert my database from Sql Server to MySql, the JPA `@GeneratedValue` does not work, return `null`, the code like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Should I change some properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the generation strategy

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Basically there are 4 types of generation strategy:

- Auto
- Identity
- Sequence
- Table

Comment: @GeneratedValue have default value(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) ,when the database is MySql ,the value is AUTO_INCREMENT,isn't that?

Comment: AUTO actually means "the JPA provider chooses" ... not AUTO_INCREMENT. So you cannot bank on any particular one being used unless you choose IDENTITY, SEQUENCE or TABLE.

Comment: As already mentioned by @NeilStockton. GenerationType.AUTO makes JPA Provider to decide on the generation strategy, it may choose Table based or sequence based strategy so it is good that the data source you have has high privilege (It has to create a table or sequence and these are high privilege operations often restricted)